# Moving element when window resize

Tags: css, html

I have a model popup div which overlay the window. When this div is active the content elements of this div moves when I resize the window.

css code:

```
     .modalBackground {

                background-color: #808080;
                filter: alpha(opacity=40);
                /*opacity:0.5;  */
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 10;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            }
 .progress 
        { 
            position:relative; 
            width:445px; 
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 1px; 
            border-radius: 3px; 
            margin-left:35%; 
            background-color:transparent !important; 
            margin-top:4%;
            text-align:center !important;
        }

        .bar 
        { 
            background-color:  #B4F5B4 !important; 
            width:50%; 
            height:20px; 
            border-radius: 3px; 
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#EA7350,#FF662F) !important;
        }

        .percent 
        { 
            position:absolute; 
            display:inline-block; 
            top:3px; 
            left:48%; 
            color:black; 

        }
```

Html code for this css

```
 <div id="popupdiv" class="modalBackground"> @* style="display:none;"  *@
                            <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;">

                                     <div class="progress" >
                                        <div class="bar"></div >
                                        <div class="percent">0%</div >
                                    </div>

                                <input type="button" id="cancel" class="gray-btn" name="Cancel" value="Cancel Upload.."   onclick="textHiddenCancel.value = 'cancel';" style="width:8%; margin-left:55%; background-color:#E2611E!important;"/>

                             </div>

                        </div>
```

Did research but didn't found any solution yet. Please help me out in this.
[**link**](http://jsbin.com/zodeto/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: What is the question here? Solution to what?

Comment: can u create fiddel for this problem.

Comment: modify the **width:445px;**   .give in Percentage like 60%; in  **.progress** class

Comment: tried with 60%, doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modalBackground {

                background-color: #808080;
                filter: alpha(opacity=40);
                /*opacity:0.5;  */
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 10;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            }
 .progress 
        { 
            position:relative; 
            width:30%; 
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 1px; 
            border-radius: 3px; 
            margin-left:35%; 
            background-color:transparent !important; 
            margin-top:4%;
            text-align:center !important;
        }

        .bar 
        { 
            background-color:  #B4F5B4 !important; 
            width:50%; 
            height:20px; 
            border-radius: 3px; 
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#EA7350,#FF662F) !important;
        }

        .percent 
        { 
            position:absolute; 
            display:inline-block; 
            top:3px; 
            left:48%; 
            color:black; 

        }
```

```html
<div id="popupdiv" class="modalBackground"> @* style="display:none;"  *@
                            <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;">

                                     <div class="progress" >
                                        <div class="bar"></div >
                                        <div class="percent">0%</div >
                                    </div>

                                <input type="button" id="cancel" class="gray-btn" name="Cancel" value="Cancel Upload.."   onclick="textHiddenCancel.value = 'cancel';" style="width:8%; margin-left:55%; background-color:#E2611E!important;"/>

                             </div>

                        </div>
```

Try width in percentage

Comment: No it doesn't work. i want the content to be static should not move when i resize the browser window.